# Kill shell script process by name

Tags: bash, kill, ps

I have a script running in background like this:

```
nohup /tmp/a.sh &
```

If the script is running for more than 5 mins, I want to `kill` it.

```
-bash-3.2$ nohup /tmp/a.sh &
[1] 2518
-bash-3.2$ nohup: appending output to `nohup.out'

-bash-3.2$ ps -ef | grep /tmp/a.sh
ordev  2518 17827  0 15:24 pts/3    00:00:00 /bin/sh /tmp/a.sh
ordev  2525 17827  0 15:24 pts/3    00:00:00 grep /tmp/a.sh
-bash-3.2$
-bash-3.2$ killall /tmp/a.sh  # killall not working like this
/tmp/a.sh: no process killed
```

If I use `killall` like below, it tries to kill all sessions running `/bin/sh`:

```
-bash-3.2$ killall sh /tmp/a.sh
sh(17822): Operation not permitted  # this pid associated with another process under root user. 
/tmp/a.sh: no process killed
[1]+  Terminated              nohup /tmp/a.sh .
```

Other than `pkill -f`, are there any alternatives that kill only the required script name?

Comment: `timeout 5m urcommandhere`

Comment: What's wrong with `pkill -f`?

Comment: Also, note that `nohup /tmp/a.sh &` prints the pid.  In your example, you could just do `kill 2518` at the end.

Comment: @Mikel : yes, pkill-f works fine, but just exploring how i can use killall.

Comment: Because `killall` is looking for something that matches the first arg for a process's CMD. [For instance](https://dpaste.de/Xdsk)

Comment: That command is also pretty dangerous considering you also told it to kill anything running under `sh` which is probably a great deal of things. Including things you don't want to kill off.

Comment: @Bratchley : So finally pkill -f is good way to terminate ?

Comment: It's a question of preference as well as what you're trying to do. I prefer `killall` because it's what I'm familiar with but they each have different options. For what you're doing `killall` can work you just need to use it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the pid of the started process and save it to the file. Before spawning a new instance, check that the old has finished. Otherwise, kill it.

```
echo "Starting a new A instance"
nohup /tmp/a.sh &
echo "Writing A pid to file"
echo $! > /tmp/a_pid
```

Then you can check time and kill the script as:

```
if [ -f /tmp/a_pid ]; then
    echo "Trying to stop previous instance of proces A"
    kill $(cat /tmp/a_pid) || true
    echo "Removing A pid file"
    rm /tmp/a_pid
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessary to kill by name. I recommend you save the PID of the script every time you run it, then call that PID from a file when you want to kill it. Like:

```
nohup /tmp/a.sh &
echo $! > a_pid
```

Then to kill it, do:

```
ps -9 ` a_pid`
```

Note $! gives the last command run which will be nohup `nohup /tmp/a.sh &`

Comment: `ps`? `-9`??  I'd suggest `kill $!`.